# Does it make sense to use async with code that has no sleep()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I've read a lot of different articles that explain the `async` in Python. But they all give an example with `asyncio.sleep(x)`, like this one:

```
import asyncio

async def test1 ():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(1)

async def test2 ():
    print(2)

async def main ():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2())

asyncio.run(main()) #prints 2, then 1
```

And in this case everything's clear for me: await in function test1 says that during the execution of asyncio.sleep we can do something other, for example execute function test2.

What I don't understand, is that how can the async be useful, if I don't use sleeps in my code? How can I run functions concurrently in that case? For example, how do I run concurrently functions test1 and test2 in the example below?

```
import asyncio
import time

async def calculate (a):
    return a**a

async def test1 ():
    x = await calculate(1111111)
    print('done!')

async def test2 ():
    for i in range(100):
        print('.', end='')

async def main ():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2())

asyncio.run(main()) #prints 'done!' before the dots
```

Comment: I would add that each chain of `await`s that ends with `yield` (e.g.,`await some_future` comes down to this.) is an opportunity to execute the code asynchronously. If your functions that you `await` do not `await` functions that use `asyncio` capabilities, e.g. `asyncio.sleep()`, but simply return a result, then there is no benefit from `asyncio` in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, would you maybe like to elaborate your comment into a full answer about CPU- and IO-bound tasks? Since this question still receives some attention, I feel obligated to give it an accepted answer. But it seems a little unfair to basically write what you said with details and accept it, so that's why I am asking you.

Comment: @Mortasen: there you go, posted below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asyncio is great when you have code that **needs to wait for things**. Every `await` statement is an opportunity for other code to run, code that no longer has to wait for things.

The easiest, simplest way for documentation to show that something is waiting, is the `asyncio.sleep()` function, because that's simple and easy to understand. Moreover, it doesn't require external libraries or network services for it to work.

There are loads of things that might have to wait:

- Any network interaction involves loads of waiting; network communication is guaranteed to be slower than your Python code.
- Filesystem I/O also has to wait a lot, because even when using SSDs and caches, I/O is slower than CPU cycles. (caveat: there are not many options to exploit this from asyncio yet, because OS support is lacking. Libraries for `asyncio` file I/O tend to fall back to using threads instead).
- Interprocess communication (e.g. where you'd use the `subprocess` module elsewhere), because the OS, not your code, decides when the other program will run and produce output.
- Coordination between different tasks, where one thing will have to wait until something else is done. Usually those other things are not done yet because they are waiting for something.
- Interacting with humans involves waiting too, because people are way, *way* slower than computers.

Any use of higher-level constructs such as a database will involve many of the above, so be sure to check if there is an `asyncio`-compatible library that'll let you do what you want for those.

In your second example hardly anything waits. The only point where the code has to wait a little, is when you used `print()`, because that involves I/O (writing to the terminal), but `print()` is not built to work with `asyncio` so your code can't do anything else while that happens. `print()` is a *blocking* function, which means that asyncio can't do anything else while blocked. For asyncio to shine, you want to avoid blocking.

I've included a more complex example below, a script that downloads multiple URLs listed in a file given on the command line. It makes use of the [`aiohttp` library](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) to handle HTTP requests, [`aiofiles`](https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles/) for file I/O, and [`tqdm`](https://tqdm.github.io/) to display progress bars. It can be configured for how many URLs it'll process in parallel. Disclaimer: I am a contributor to the `aiohttp` project, but not a very active one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio
import traceback
from contextlib import AsyncExitStack, contextmanager

import aiofiles
import aiohttp
import tqdm

@contextmanager
def put_exceptions(log, *exceptions):
    exceptions = exceptions or (Exception,)
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions:
        log(f"Exception: {traceback.format_exc()}")

def filename_from_response(response):
    disp = response.content_disposition
    if disp and disp.filename:
        return filename
    return response.url.name

async def worker(queue, session, main_progress):
    async with AsyncExitStack() as worker_context:
        worker_context.enter_context(put_exceptions(print))
        while True:
            url = await queue.get()
            async with AsyncExitStack() as task_context:
                task_context.callback(queue.task_done)
                task_context.callback(main_progress.update)
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                    filename = filename_from_response(response)
                    size = int(response.headers.get("content-length", 0)) or None
                    pbar = tqdm.tqdm(
                        desc=filename,
                        leave=False,
                        total=size,
                        unit="iB",
                        unit_scale=True,
                        unit_divisor=1024,
                        colour="cyan",
                    )
                    task_context.callback(pbar.close)
                    async with aiofiles.open(filename, "wb") as outf:
                        while chunk := await response.content.read(8192):
                            await outf.write(chunk)
                            pbar.update(len(chunk))
                        pbar.refresh()

 async def main(input_file, worker_count):
     with tqdm.tqdm(
         total=0, unit="f", colour="green", miniters=1, smoothing=0.1
     ) as pbar:
         queue = asyncio.Queue()
         async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
             workers = [
                 asyncio.create_task(worker(queue, session, pbar), name=f"worker{i + 1}")
                 for i in range(worker_count)
             ]
             async with aiofiles.open(input_file) as f:
                 async for url in f:
                     queue.put_nowait(url)
                     pbar.total += 1
                     pbar.refresh()
             await queue.join()
             for worker_task in workers:
                 worker_task.cancel()
             await asyncio.wait(workers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Download URLs to disk, given an input file listing the URLS"
    )
    parser.add_argument("filename")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-w", dest="worker_count", help="worker count", default=5, type=int
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        asyncio.run(main(args.filename, args.worker_count))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

When in use, it looks like this (sample URLs taken from [this set of sample satellite images](https://effigis.com/en/solutions/satellite-images/satellite-image-samples/)):

[image: terminal screen showing script output with progress bars for several URLs]

The script creates a number of extra tasks, each executing the `worker()` coroutine, which uses a shared session object to make a HTTP request for the URL, after which a loop pulls in the response data in chunks to write to disk; this makes it possible to also monitor progress. There are loads of points of waiting, now:

- The input file is read, line by line, in a `async for` loop. This means that if the script has to wait for the OS to produce data from disk, the script can do something else.
- Each worker first has to wait for URLs to be made available, via a queue.
- Once they have a URL, the `async with session.get()` call leads to network operations that will have to wait for a remote server to start responding.
- For each response that comes back, we have to wait for more data to arrive from the remote server.
- For each chunk of data that arrived, writing to disk will take more waiting still.
- Once all URLs have been read from the input file, the main function has to wait for the workers to empty the queue, and then to finish downloading the URLs they are still processing.

The tqdm progress bars should at least make it easier to see that things are still moving, and that the downloads and disk writes are happening in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with ***tasks***.

***Tasks*** are used to schedule coroutines concurrently.

When a coroutine is wrapped into a Task with functions like `asyncio.create_task()` (see [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) ) the coroutine is automatically scheduled to run soon:

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def calculate(a):
    return a**a


async def test1():
    # Schedule calculate(a) to run soon concurrently
    # with "main()".
    task = asyncio.create_task(calculate(11111))

    # "task" can now be used to cancel "calculate(a)", or
    # can simply be awaited to wait until it is complete:
    await task
    print('done!')


async def dots_printer():
    for i in range(100):
        print('.', end='')
        

async def test2():
    # Schedule dots_printer() to run soon concurrently
    # with "main()".
    task = asyncio.create_task(dots_printer())

    # "task" can now be used to cancel "dots_printer()", or
    # can simply be awaited to wait until it is complete:
    await task


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2())


asyncio.run(main()) #prints the dots before 'done!'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example code, try commenting and un-commenting the first and second lines in the `if __main__` block. And you will see the difference.

```
import requests # pip install requests
import asyncio


urls = ["http://example.com"] * 20

async def async_get(url):
    response = await asyncio.to_thread(requests.get, url)
    return response


async def async_main():
    tasks = [async_get(url) for url in urls]
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return responses


def get(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response

def sync_main():
    responses = []
    for url in urls:
        responses.append(get(url))
    return responses


if __name__ == '__main__':

    responses = asyncio.run(async_main())
    # responses = sync_main()

    print([response.status_code for response in responses])
```